Docker "error: cannot find module bcrypt and argon2" on bun app with hono, better-sqlite3 and lucia
Trying to dockerize a Bun app, I faced those 3 following issues when running my container:
bun-app-1  | error: Cannot find module "@node-rs/argon2-wasm32-wasi" from "/app/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js"

bun-app-1  | error: Cannot find module "@node-rs/bcrypt-wasm32-wasi" from "/app/node_modules/@node-rs/bcrypt/binding.js"

bun-app-1  | error: Cannot find module "@node-rs/argon2-linux-arm64-gnu" from "/app/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js"

bun-app-1 exited with code 1

Locally, everything works fine (bun run src/index.tsx in my terminal). The moment I try to run this with Docker, it crashes.
I'm newbie with Docker so I'm not sure if this error is related to my docker config. Don't hesitate to correct me on this point or guide me in a better way to track issues (I know that bcrypt and argon2 are related to oslo, which is recommended to use with lucia).
Here below are my docker-compose and dockerfiles:
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  bun-app:
    image: oven/bun:1.0.25-slim
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
     - 3000:3000
    
    env_file:
      - ./.env

Dockerfile.dev
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
ARG BUN_VERSION=1.0.25-slim
FROM oven/bun:${BUN_VERSION} as base

LABEL fly_launch_runtime="Bun"

WORKDIR /app

# Set production environment
ENV NODE_ENV="development"

ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT

COPY package.json bun.lockb ./

FROM base AS development

RUN bun install
COPY . .
CMD ["bun", "run", "src/index.tsx"]

Dockerfile.prod
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Adjust BUN_VERSION as desired
ARG BUN_VERSION=1.0.25-slim
FROM oven/bun:${BUN_VERSION} as base

LABEL fly_launch_runtime="Bun"

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json bun.lockb ./

# Set production environment
ENV NODE_ENV="production"

FROM base AS build

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential node-gyp pkg-config python-is-python3 ; 

# Install node modules
COPY --link bun.lockb package.json ./
RUN bun install --ci

# Copy application code
COPY --link . .


# Final stage for app image
FROM base

# Copy built application
COPY --from=build /app /app
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["bun", "run", "src/index.tsx"]


My first step here would be to delete the volumes: block that hides absolutely everything in these images.  If the libraries are missing from the anonymous volume that holds node_modules, there's no way to add them in.

I deleted it...nothing changed unfortunately :/
What can be the reasons those librairies are not downloaded ?
